# how to integrate lighthouse with git?

Tags: git, lighthouse

I'm trying to achieve something like github's support for closing tickets com the commit message, that is, if you issue

```
git commit -m "fixes #4"
```

github automatically closes the ticket #4

In this case I'm using lighthouse with a git repo, and I was wondering if it's possible to achieve that functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API for lighthouse to close tickets. You can write a post receive hook to do that for you.

Or try this, I found it somewhere online.

```
git commit -m "Make some change that resolves ticket 66 [#66 state:resolved]"
```

Comment: yeap, I've also found that sample somewhere on google, but I tried it and it didn't work...

Comment: It should work. Says so right in the lighthouse manual. 
http://help.lighthouseapp.com/kb/ticket-workflow/ticket-keyword-updates . 
I guess if this doesn't work, you'd probably be better off getting this resolved on the lighthouse-specific support channels that the company provides than on stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you able to update ticket status by sending emails? If you are able to do that, then you can setup a post receive hook in git to send the appropriate email message when you do a push. 
Again, you have to write your own script to do that. They already have a similar script for SVN at http://help.lighthouseapp.com/kb/api/scm-integration